# NPE when trying to remove an element from ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList of Objects, and each object has a list of string members.

I'm trying to iterate through the list and remove any member of the list that has a specific element (status) that is null.

the objects elements are set to null in their constructor, and remain null if they are not filled in. I can't understand why I'm getting an NPE. I've debugged it and i can step through the loop and see each element and their members, but once i hit an element who's member "status" is null, I'm getting an NPE.

Any help appreciated.

```
    public ArrayList<FlightObject> processResults(ArrayList<FlightObject> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).status.toString() == null) {
            list.remove(i);

        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: And the stacktrace ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24100776/829571

Comment: is `list.get(i)=null`? or `list.get(i).status=null`

Comment: is `status` is `null`, then `status.toString()` will throw NPE!

Comment: This cannot work `if (list.get(i).status.toString() == null)`. change `if (list.get(i).status.toString() == null)` to `if (list.get(i).status == null)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the NPE issue can be resolved with a simple null check like `if (list.get(i).status == null)` but you will encounter another issue once you correct that right. Changing the list that you actually traverse over is a bad idea cause you are going to probably miss some cases as you will skip over some of the elements ("you change the indexes"). To do that correctly you'll need and iterator like this:

```
public ArrayList<FlightObject> processResults(ArrayList<FlightObject> list) {
    for (Iterator<FlightObject> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        FlightObject fo = iter.next();   
        if (fo.status == null) {
            iter.remove();            
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Someone at least saw the bug! +1

Answer (score 4):

When `list.get(i).status` is `null`, invoking any method on it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

The check should be simply `if (list.get(i).status == null) {`

Comment: How about `list.get(i)` becoming null ?

Comment: I just assumed all elements are not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public ArrayList<FlightObject> processResults(ArrayList<FlightObject> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i)!=null && list.get(i).status!= null){
                list.remove(i);    
            }
          }
        }
        return list;
    }
```